# CENTOS 7/Win10 unable to access SMB share from windows/mac

Tags: smbclient

I am able to access my SMB on the linux box itself with smbclient with

smbclient -U user //server/winbkup

or mounting with the file explore GUI.

my windows computer is on WORKGROUP, and on linux side I created the username and did smbpasswd -a NEWUSER

here is what my smb.conf looks like (pasting global the custom share)

[global]
    workgroup = WORKGROUP
    netbios name = SERVER
    security = user

```
passdb backend = tdbsam

printing = cups
printcap name = cups
load printers = yes
cups options = raw
```

[winbkup]
    path = /mnt/storage/winbkup
    read only = no
    browseable = yes
    valid users = NEWUSER
[osxbkup]
    path = /mnt/storage/osxbkup
    read only = no
    browseable = yes
    valid users = NEWUSER

For permission and ownership I did.

chmod 775 /mnt/storage/winbkup
chown NEWUSER:NEWUSER /mnt/storage/winbkup

same for the osxfolder

Also in windows host file I added the ip address to the hostname of the linux box, but this is just DNS, i realized that.

And I made sure SMB 1.0 / CIFS feature is enabled on Windows 10

I tried mapping by \SERVER\winbkup or \IP\winbkup or just by \SERVER or \IP

and from centos I can do smb://server/winbkup. Even tried on my mac with smb://IP/winbkup/ or with hostname, or smb://NEWUSER:*@

no luck, it seems like I can't reach the server. Could this be a firewall Issue? Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was firewall if anyone else is having issue try these two commands

## firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-service=samba

## firewall-cmd --reload

I would like to give credit to this blog
https://www.tecmint.com/install-samba4-on-centos-7-for-file-sharing-on-windows/

althought i did not use those configuration but that two commands did the trick.